# Програмный клик по элементу селекта

Tags: javascript

есть ссылка и пункт селекта, подскажите как программно при клике по ссылке сделать как будто пользователь выбрал елемент селекта (т.е. кликнул по нему мышкой)

Comment: присвой селекту необходимое значение

Comment: @Grundy т.е.  установить атрибут selected.

Comment: нет. установить свойство _value_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
function selectChange(val){
 let select = document.getElementsByTagName("select")[0];
  select.selectedIndex = val;
}
```

```html
<select id="select">
  <option value="1" selected>1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>

<button onclick="selectChange(0);">1</button>
<button onclick="selectChange(1);">2</button>
<button onclick="selectChange(2);">3</button>
```

Comment: Будьте осторожны. При таком подходе события, такие как `onclick` или `onchange`, которые есть у тега **<select>** не будут срабатывать.